# Unable to render the data from models to view in django framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

When i try to run a server,I am getting an error where  it shows TypeError: 'Organization' object is not iterable. I am attaching the Model and views for the reference. Can you check and determine why i am getting the error.

'''
    Model.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ticket_status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    orgname = models.ForeignKey(Organization, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Ticket_status, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticket_id

'''




views.py

'''
----------- 

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from.models import *

# Create your views here.
def organization(request, orgname):
    organization_name=Organization.objects.get(id=orgname)
    organization_count=Organization.objects.get(id=orgname).ticket_set.all()



    return render(request,'ticket\organization1.html',{'organization_name':organization_name,' organization_count': organization_count})
'''
```

template
This is the template file(ticket\organization1.html).Can you check and determine why i am getting the error?
'''

```
{% extends 'ticket/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Organization Name</h5>
              <P> {% for t in organization_name %}
                  {{t.name}}
                  {% endfor %}
                  </P>
            <p class="card-text"></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Active Ticket</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{ organization_count.count }}
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Closed Ticket</h5>
            <p class="card-text">2.</p>
            <!--a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <br>
        <div>
            <h2>On-Going Tickets</h2><br>

        </div>
      <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>S NO</th>
                            <th>Ticket ID</th>
                            <th>Organization</th>
                            <th>Ticket Status</th>
                            <br>
                        </tr>
                            {% for t in organization_name %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{t.Ticket_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{t.Ticket_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{t.organization}}</td>
                                    <td>{{t.Ticket_Status}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                    </table>
      </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}'''
```

Comment: welcome to SO. can you add your template to your question ?

Comment: In the `ticket\organization1.html` template you can iterate over `organization_count`, but not `organization_name`. I'm guessing you're trying to iterate over `organization_name` which is a single Organization instance.

Comment: or you are trying to render organization {{organization_name}} , it will be {{organization_name.name}}

Comment: @Ben, is there a way to make Organization as multiple instance so that I can get the data.

Comment: organization_name is getting the value. When I add the line for organization_count it is throwing the error

Comment: Organization.objects.get() is going to give you one object, Organization.objects.filter() will give you a QuerySet you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first

```
<P> {% for t in organization_name %}
    {{t.name}}
```

should be

```
<P> {{ organization_name.name }}  # organization_name is an object
```

your second

```
{% for t in organization_name %}
```

should be

```
{% for t in organization_count %}  # organization_count is a list of tickets
    <td>{{t.ticket_id}}</td>
    <td>{{organization_name.name}}</td>  # single object, same as above
    <td>{{t.status}}</td>
```